# Compute crazy complex integral involving $e$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Show as $R \rightarrow \infty$ that

$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\vert z \vert = R} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^k}dz=0$$

for all $k \geq 2$. No clue on how to even begin. Here, is $z = Re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and $R \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: [Avoid “no clue” questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969)

Comment: Try using residue theorem and the fact that 0 is a singularity. To compute the value of the residue use the laurent expansion

Comment: z=Re^{i\theta} and not what you have. Then my hint is that you can plug the values in and use the fact that |\int "inside" dz|\leq \int |"inside"|dz

Comment: Learn what "$|z|=R$" means *before* trying to solve such integrals.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe damn why so harsh Im barely learning.

Comment: is this a complex analysis question?

Comment: You may not need to calculate explicitly the "crazy" integral. What you need to do is to show it tends to zero. You may use "M-L" estimate

Comment: when is this integral taught?

Comment: @LOL in a graduate complex analysis course.

Comment: damn, im just in grade 11 and was totally baffed by seeing this

Comment: @LOL I need to take this course in the coming years, and im still baffled lol

Comment: you're not in college or uni?

Comment: I am attending this fall for PhD in math @LOL just tryna get a head start on the exercises.

Comment: good luck for the PhD, and btw can you solve this: $\int\frac{x+1}{2x^{3/2}}$

Comment: do you write the integrand as a sum of 1/x + 1/x^{3/2}? then integrate? @LOL

Comment: Another strategy: The inversion map $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ sends $|z|=R$ to $|z|=\frac{1}{R}$ and transforms your contour integral to $-\oint_{|z|=\frac{1}{R}}z^{k-2}e^z\mathrm{d}z$ whose integrand is analytic in any disc centered about the origin.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Sorry if my comment sounded harsh, it was not supposed to be. Your post seems to indicate that your trouble with the question is not related to the integral, but rather about what "$|z|=R$" means. So it seems natural to advise you to learn things that get you into trouble *before* attempting any question that uses it.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame thanks i did it with your technique

Comment: @LOL was that a problem you were stuck on? so write $\frac{x+1}{2x^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$

Comment: @LOL yes, sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use residue theorem.

$$e^{1/z}=1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{6z^3}+\dots$$
$$\frac{e^{1/z}}{z^k}=\frac{1}{z^k}+\frac{1}{z^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2z^{2+k}}+\frac{1}{6z^{3+k}}+\dots$$

So the residue of $\frac{e^{1/z}}{z^2}$ in $z=0$ is $0$ because the residue is the coefficient $a_{-1}$ of the expansion.
So $$\int_{|z|=R} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^{k}} \; dz =0$$
And that holds for every $R>0$ because the only singularity of the function inside the contour is in $z=0$